# How to add an auto current date columns?

Tags: sql, db2, ddl

How can I add a column (or if not possible to ADD how do I create a table contining such a column, using DDL) to a table that is an AUTO-pupulate type and populates with current date? So basically when I load data from a .csv file I want the new column to record the date when I run the upload. I am using DB2.

Comment: So you want to have for each insert/upload on your table, the related date of the insert/upload ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax below is valid on current versions of Db2 for Linux/Windows/Unix and may also be valid on other platforms:

```
alter table .... add column ... DATE with default curent date;
```

or

```
alter table ... add column ... TIMESTAMP with default current timestamp;
```

You can also use triggers to populate the new column, is is suitable only for plain insert/update (and import and ingest) but not LOAD .

When using load or import/ingest , omit this column from the target list of columns and it will then default to the given value at the time of the insert.

Comment: if your Db2 platform & version supports it, a ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP may be a better choice.  `alter table ... add column ... TIMESTAMP NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP`